# TypeError: n.split is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I wrote a code, it works normally in my editor, but when i upload it to codewars, i saw a error code TypeError: n.split is not a function

I tried to add "n.toString()"(i saw it in other question) but it doesn't work. What i did wrong?

```js
"use strict"
let sum = 0;
function digital_root(n) {
    n.toString();
    let arr = 
    (n).split("").map(Number);
    for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
} 
console.log(digital_root("16"));
```

Comment: `n.toString();` does nothing, you need capture it's return value: `n = n.toString();`

Comment: I just submitted your code to codewars and it worked just fine...

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually set n to it's string representation.

```js
let sum = 0;
function digital_root(n) {
    n = n.toString();
    let arr = n.split("").map(Number);
    for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
} 
console.log(digital_root("16"));
```

Comment: `n` is already a string, so that really does nothing.